# Edit video like professional gamers

Tags: video-editor, editing

I want to make a gaming video. I have the clips and here is the layout:
[image]

Can any free PC apps help/do this?
Thanks

Comment: You can either do it with a NLE (Giving you much more capabilitys than only that) or record your clip with OBS and blend in the camera there

Comment: Here is a beginners guide to game streaming, which should contain everything you need to get started (including setting up OBS). It was I need to get up and running in less than an hour.. See Live Streaming 101 – My https://jeffreyfritz.com/2017/12/live-streaming-101-my-setup/#more-7214

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways: 1) as above, set your webcam in the video in post production of 2) record the video with the webcam in, for example with [OBS](https://obsproject.com/download) or [SLOBS](https://streamlabs.com/streamlabs-obs).

Comment: OBS will also give an extra ability to stream with your camera visible

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

Any NLE can do this: you're simply going to insert/layer an image over another.

Here's how to do it with Premiere Pro (if you have access to that program; the same principle applies to any other NLE though)